# Associated type not found in the current scope when returning from pattern match inside method

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, pattern-matching, associated-types

I have [this code (bb42e59)](https://github.com/brokenthorn/bizpharma_core):

```
pub extern crate r2d2;
pub extern crate tiberius;
pub extern crate futures;

use self::tiberius::BoxableIo;
use self::futures::prelude::*;

use core::fmt::Debug;
#[allow(unused_imports)]
use std::error::Error;

type TiberiusConnection = self::tiberius::SqlConnection<Box<BoxableIo>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Errors { TiberiusError(tiberius::Error) }

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MSSQLConnectionManagerError(Errors);

impl ::std::error::Error for MSSQLConnectionManagerError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        match self.0 {
            Errors::TiberiusError(ref e) => {
                match e {
                    tiberius::Error::Io(e) => e.description(),
                    tiberius::Error::Protocol(msg) => &msg,
                    tiberius::Error::Encoding(msg) => &msg,
                    tiberius::Error::Conversion(msg) => &msg,
                    tiberius::Error::Utf8(e) => e.description(),
                    tiberius::Error::Utf16(e) => e.description(),
                    tiberius::Error::ParseInt(e) => e.description(),
                    // TODO: parse the server token if possible and report the actual error that occurred, like invalid login, etc.
                    tiberius::Error::Server(_) => "TDS token error occurred! When connecting, most often an invalid login.",
                    tiberius::Error::Canceled => "Canceled!",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl ::std::fmt::Display for MSSQLConnectionManagerError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut ::std::fmt::Formatter) -> ::std::fmt::Result {
        match self.0 { Errors::TiberiusError(ref e) => e.fmt(f), }
    }
}

pub struct MSSQLConnection(TiberiusConnection);

pub struct MSSQLConnectionManager { connection_string: String }

impl MSSQLConnectionManager {
    pub fn new(connection_string: String) -> MSSQLConnectionManager {
        MSSQLConnectionManager { connection_string }
    }

    pub fn from_env() -> Result<MSSQLConnectionManager, ::std::env::VarError> {
        let connection_string = ::std::env::var("MSSQL_CONNECTION_STRING")?;
        Ok(MSSQLConnectionManager { connection_string })
    }
}

impl r2d2::ManageConnection for MSSQLConnectionManager {
    type Connection = MSSQLConnection;
    type Error = MSSQLConnectionManagerError;

    fn connect(&self) -> Result<Self::Connection, Self::Error> {
        let connection_result = TiberiusConnection::connect(&self.connection_string)
            .and_then(|c| Ok(c)).wait();
        match connection_result {
            Ok(c) => Ok(MSSQLConnection(c)),
            Err(e) => Err(MSSQLConnectionManagerError(Errors::TiberiusError(e))),
        }
    }

    fn is_valid(&self, _conn: &mut Self::Connection) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        // TODO: Fix this quick and dirty implementation by checking the result of a simple query.
        Ok(())
    }

    fn has_broken(&self, _conn: &mut Self::Connection) -> bool {
        // TODO: Fix this quick and dirty implementation by checking underlying TCP socket state.
        false
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about `Ok(c) => Ok(Self::Connection(c)),`:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `Connection` found for type `persistence::mssql::MSSQLConnectionManager` in the current scope
  --> src/persistence/mssql.rs:77:25
   |
56 | pub struct MSSQLConnectionManager { connection_string: String }
   | --------------------------------- associated item `Connection` not found for this
...
77 |             Ok(c) => Ok(Self::Connection(c)),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `persistence::mssql::MSSQLConnectionManager`
```

When I write it explicitly, like this:

```
match connection_result {
    Ok(c) => Ok(MSSQLConnection(c)),
    Err(e) => Err(MSSQLConnectionManagerError(Errors::TiberiusError(e))),
}
```

Now it compiles successfully.
I do get the same compiler error though if I try this with L10, by returning `Err(Self::Error(e))`.

Why doesn't this work as I expect?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sorry. I've just been scratching my head for a long time while trying to find any clue about why my code doesn't compile and then kind of rushed at SO when I couldn't take it anymore.

Comment: The code you have provided does not compile due to syntax errors. Please try it yourself locally before posting it to ensure it produces the same error as you originally had.

Comment: *scratching my head for a long time while trying to find any clue about why my code doesn't compile* — bluntly, if you had spent some of that time creating a MCVE, it's entirely likely you would have solved the problem yourself. In the rare case that you didn't, you'd be eminently prepared to ask a question here, on an issue tracker, on a forum, to a fellow programmer, etc.

Comment: Why are you using `core` instead of `std`? Why are you re-exporting crates? Why are you importing things and not using them? Since the code continues to not compile, I can only ask these vague questions based on non-idiomatic code choices.

Comment: OK, this is embarrassing. I've now pasted my entire module. Let me just be clear. The syntax is correct. The code compiles when the pattern match returns `Ok(c) => Ok(MSSQLConnection(c))`, but I expected it to compile asl well when using the associated type `Connection`, since `type Connection = MSSQLConnection`.

Comment: It's pretty much worth taking your time to write a good question from the start. While we do understand that you might have been troubled by this issue for a while, rushing the question is one of the things worth avoiding the most on SO. with that said, that error message seems to be just an attempt to look for the associated type `Connect` in the implementing type `MSSQLConnectionManager` rather than the implemented trait `ConnectionManager`. Does replacing `Ok(Self::Connection(c))` with `Ok(<Self as r2d2::ManageConnection>::Connection(c))` help?

Comment: The code you have provided does not compile: ``failed to resolve. Maybe a missing `extern crate core;`?``. If I change it to `std::` then the code compiles successfully. Please try it yourself locally before posting it to ensure it produces the same error as you originally had.

Comment: The `core` vs `std` import is not the problem. It compiled with either for me. Do you want me to record my screen to prove it? I can understand why I should be scolded for posting a bad question but please don't assume I'm lying. Rather just tell me if you think so. And the `core` import was just an artifact of CLion auto-import. I'm using `rustc 1.29.1 (b801ae664 2018-09-20)`, btw.

Comment: @E_net4, No. I tried even though it seems to me like associated types are just declared in traits but defined in impls of them so it makes no sense to scope and cast like in your example. Finally, your suggestion yields this error: `error[E0575]: expected method or associated constant, found associated type 'r2d2::ManageConnection::Connection'`

Comment: It might be worth specifying a few more things about your project: Rust compiler version and the Cargo.lock come to mind. We are not implying that you're lying, but if we're grabbing the code that you have provided and we cannot reproduce the problem, we have no choice but to say there's a missing variable in the question.

Comment: @E_net4 OK, I'll try and wrap up a commit of a working, compiling version and then link you to the code.

Comment: Here's [a link to the code repository | bb42e59](https://github.com/brokenthorn/bizpharma_core) so you can check it out. The master branch compiles for me and tests are all passing. I already mentioned that I'm using Rust stable but I'll mention it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the same issue. Some type names were changed for clarity.

```
trait Manager {
    type Connection;

    fn connect(&self) -> Self::Connection;
}

pub struct ConnectionId(usize);

pub struct FooManager;

impl Manager for FooManager {
    type Connection = ConnectionId;

    fn connect(&self) -> Self::Connection {
        Self::Connection(5)
    }
}
```

The error emerges from attempting to use the associated type `Connection` like an alias to the concrete type `ConnectionId`, as defined by the implementation of `Manager`. However, associated types do not behave entirely like a type alias. Even though we can construct a `ConnectionId` (as it is a tuple struct, and we have visibility towards its member in this module), we cannot do that through the associated type `Self::Connection`. What we could do is access other symbols defined by its constraints. For example, if we had this:

```
trait Manager {
    type Connection: Default;
    // ...
}
```

We would be able to call `default` from `Self::Connection`.

As such, changing the expression `Ok(Self::Connection(c))` in the original example to `Ok(MSSQLConnection(c)),` is the right way to fix this. In the event that you need to abstract the type away even at this step, you can constrain the associated type to a new trait providing the necessary construction methods.

Comment: So constructing through type aliases is not supported. Now that I understood the issue, I google'd and [found this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.0/reference/items/type-aliases.html): `A type alias [...] cannot be used to qualify the constructors`. So type aliases only help to shorten type definitions like those with several bounded types, resulting in a more concise type name. So they can only be used to define the type of a variable, a function return type or an argument type. Thanks for helping me understand this.

Comment: @Paul That seems to me it. The key takeaway is that type aliases and associated types behave differently, despite syntactical similarities with each other.

Comment: But they share the same limitation that I listed, right?

Comment: @brokenthorn Yes, that would be a common limitation.